# How to customize result in T-Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
           (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(CB_Account_Code)
            FROM Correspondent_Bank
                 WHERE Correspondent_Bank.CB_Cnt_Code = Contributions.Con_Cnt_Code and
                       Correspondent_Bank.CB_Prv_Code = Contributions.Con_Prv_Code and
                       Correspondent_Bank.CB_Dst_Code = Contributions.Con_Dst_Code and
                       Correspondent_Bank.CB_Cor_Code = Contributions.Con_Cor_Code) as BankAccoutCode
```

My Part of the SQL cording given below. I want to know how to move "NO RECORDS FOUND" to BankAccountCode if the records not found to specific criteria.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please add sample data which explains what you want to do here.

Comment: Do you have some application to display this data in? Then it it better handled there instead of in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `coalesce`   function which return 1st  non null valus

```
select COALESCE( (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(CB_Account_Code)
                FROM Correspondent_Bank
                     WHERE Correspondent_Bank.CB_Cnt_Code = Contributions.Con_Cnt_Code and
                           Correspondent_Bank.CB_Prv_Code = Contributions.Con_Prv_Code and
                           Correspondent_Bank.CB_Dst_Code = Contributions.Con_Dst_Code and
                           Correspondent_Bank.CB_Cor_Code = Contributions.Con_Cor_Code) ,'NO RECORDS FOUND') as BankAccoutCode
```